# Testing a method that takes a two dimensional array - but passing a unique_ptr

Tags: c++, memory-management, multidimensional-array, unique-ptr

Testing legacy code.

If I write a test for a method that takes an `int[]` as parameter, I use `unique_ptr` so I don't have to care for cleaning up allocated memory:

```
#include <memory>

bool methodToTest(int *parameter)
{
    bool result = true;
    // doing stuff
    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::unique_ptr<int[]> input(new int[99]);
    methodToTest(input.get());

    // ASSERT(blah, blah)
    return system("pause");
}
```

Can I do something similar for a function that takes an `int[][]`? Like

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

bool methodToTest(int **parameter)
{
    bool result = true;
    // doing stuff
    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //std::unique_ptr<int[][]> input;    // Compiler complains: error C2087: 'abstract declarator' : missing subscript
    //std::unique_ptr<std::unique_ptr<int[]>[]> input; // Nice structure, but how to get an int[][] from that?
    std::vector<int*> input;            // Works but I have to manually free allocated memory

    methodToTest(input.data());

    // ASSERT(blah, blah)
    return system("pause");
}
```

So, do I have to care for freeing allocated memory myself or is there some `std::` way that does that for me?

Comment: You may still *duplicate* your data: `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> owned_input;` (for owner_ship) and `std::vector<int*> input;` (for `int**` compatibility).

Comment: @Jarod42 So you allocate the memory in `owned_input` and assign each of its `vector` elements (via `.get()`) to an `int*` which you `push_back` to `input`? Nice ...

Comment: Yes, almost what you do in your answer with `std::unique_ptr<T[]>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something myself and suggest:

```
#include <memory>

bool methodToTest(int **parameter)
{
    bool result = true;
    // doing stuff
    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::unique_ptr<int*[]> input(new int*[44]);
    std::unique_ptr<int[]> inner_input(new int[89]);
    input[3] = inner_input.get();

    methodToTest(input.get());

    // ASSERT(blah)
    return system("pause");
}
```

Note that `inner_input` have to be a `vector` of `unique_ptr` if you want more than one of them.